# Discord Bot Special Text Boxes

Tags: discord, bots

I'm trying to figure out how to make these special text boxes that I've seen in some discords for my own bot, they look like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyLQL.png. I'm aware there is a way to do something similar to this that's built into discord but I'm not sure how to do this particular "style" of box if you will, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: These are called embeds, are you using discord.py or discord.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature called **Embeds**.

You can find out more about them here: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html